# 'real_of_int' and 'real' in Isabelle?

Tags: types, isabelle

What are `real_of_int`, `real` and `int` in Isabelle? They sound a bit like types, but usually types are written something like `x ::real` and these are written like `real x`.

I am having trouble proving the following statement,

```
 "S ((n*x)+(-x)) = S (n*x)*C (-x) + C (n*x)*S (-x)"
```

and I noticed that Isabelle writes it as:

```
S (real_of_int (int (n * x) + - int x)) =
S (real (n * x)) * C (real_of_int (- int x)) + C (real (n * x)) * S (real_of_int (- int x))
```

so I'd like to be able to understand what these mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When one uses Complex_Main (or a logic based on it like `HOL-Analysis`, `HOL-Probability` etc) Isabelle supports coercions from nat, int and rat into reals. These are added automatically if the types do not fit.

I.e. if `f :: real ⇒ real`, `n :: nat` and `i :: int`:

```
f n ↝ f (real n)
f i ↝ f (real_of_int i)
```

where `real :: nat ⇒ real` is the `nat` to `real` coercion (an abbreviation for `of_nat` where the range is fixed to real) and `real_of_int :: real ⇒ int` is the abbreviation for `of_int` where the range is fixed to real.

The coercions are essentially morphisms between the different numeral types, so there are many morphism lemmas available for them: `of_nat (l + n) = of_nat l + of_nat n` etc. The best is to search for them using just `of_nat` and `of_int` and not the `real_…` abbreviations.