# How can i cast nat to int in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

While doing my homework I got stuck in the following question:

> Create the function add. It returns the sum of two natural numbers.
>   Prove that it works.

I'm stuck because to write the code to prove it, I need to cast a natural number (`nat` in Isabelle) to `int`.

Here's the `add` function that I wrote:

```
primrec add :: "nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat"
  where
    add01: "add x 0 = x" |
    add02: "add x (Suc y) = Suc (add x y) "
```

To know the result I did this:

```
value "somaNat (Suc(Suc(0))) (Suc(0))"
```

It returns 3, as it should.

```
Suc(Suc(0) = 2
Suc(0) = 1
```

Also tried to create a function that cast it to int, like this:

```
primrec nat_to_int :: "nat ⇒ int"
  where
  nat_to_int02: "nat_to_int x = value x"
```

It does not work because (`value x`) can't be on the right side.

I searched for it in the tutorial that Isabelle provides, and in another one, that I found online.

The closest question I found on SO was this one:
[Casting int to nat in Isabelle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57027062/casting-int-to-nat-in-isabelle)

So, how can I cast `nat` to `int` in Isabelle?

Comment: You seem to misinterpret the other answser from [Casting int to nat in Isabelle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57027062/casting-int-to-nat-in-isabelle). It points to the function `nat :: "int ⇒ nat"` from http://isabelle.in.tum.de/library/HOL/HOL/Int.html and not to `value`. You might be interested in the function `int :: "nat ⇒ int"` there.

Comment: There was another post that provides a little bit more background information about in-built coercions of numerals in Isabelle/HOL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407342/real-of-int-and-real-in-isabelle/41407774#41407774.